# React onClick change child's style automatically

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Hello I really couldn't find an easy and automated way to make it work,
I want to have a lot of divs with modals inside so that I click on parent and change the style of It's child, states are not effective because I have to create an individual state for each block and I have them about 50 peaces, so is there some easy way to write something like `onClick={(e)=>e.firstChild.css(width:200px;height:200px;background:white)}` something like this not installing some packages and/or writing huge codes.
Please give me at least something to change the orange cubes by clicking on red ones without doing it individual, So that I copy the 4 cubes and make them 40 it will still work

```css
.big {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin: 10px;
}

.small {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="big">
  <div class="small"></div>  
</div>
<div class="big">
  <div class="small"></div>  
</div>
<div class="big">
  <div class="small"></div>  
</div>
<div class="big">
  <div class="small"></div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Are you hardcoding all 50 children? Sounds like you might want to `map()` them instead.

Comment: That's not about children, it's about the functionality that I click on parent and change the class or style of children, and yes the children I'm hardcoding I can't map them they are very individual

Comment: Can you create a sandbox example https://codesandbox.io/ with a minimal example of what you are trying to do.  In react, there are many ways to change the styles of children but we need to see some react code of what you are trying to do to help.

Comment: I want to have 50 parent divs with their 50 children (each has 1 child), I want to click on parent and change css of child, that's all, And I don't want to write 50 states for that

Answer (score 0):

This is quite simple with javascript. You select every element with class `big` and add an event listener that works on a child of that node. The main problem is that a click on the `small` child also calls the listener. I am showing a solution that allows you to respond to both events independently (if you click on the `small`, you get a console message), but there are other solutions depending on your needs.

```js
let bigs = document.querySelectorAll('.big');
bigs.forEach((el) => { 
  el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    let small = e.target.querySelector('.small');
    if (small === null){
      console.log('clicked on small');
    }
    else{
      small.style.cssText = 'width:200px;height:50px;background:white';
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.big {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin: 10px;
}

.small {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="big">
  <div class="small"></div>  
</div>
<div class="big">
  <div class="small"></div>  
</div>
<div class="big">
  <div class="small"></div>  
</div>
<div class="big">
  <div class="small"></div>  
</div>
```